# Cannot call BOOL method in IF statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and this Smalltalk syntax is quite frustrating for a new comer. I am trying to call the following method declaration in an IF statement:

```
-(BOOL) string:(NSString *)string1 containsCharInString:(NSString *)string2
```

When call it I do it like this, which I believe should work:

```
if([string1 containsCharInString: word2]) {...}
```

1. The autocomplete does not even recognise this as a method of my class
2. I get the following error when attempting to call it:

```
No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector 'containsCharInString'.
```

Comment: Are you trying to see if string1 contains char in string2?

Comment: Yes. I wrote my own method to do this though. I would just like to know how to call this method.

Comment: I've written you a book containing chapters that teach you Objective-C. Maybe you should stop and read those chapters. Start here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html

Comment: You can probably call it with `[self string:string1 containsCharInString:word2]` but that's not the cleanest way of doing it. I would suggest writing a method like this in an `NSString` category.

Comment: FYI - there is a standard way to do this instead of writing your own method. `BOOL hasChar = [string1 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string2]].location != NSNotFound;`

Comment: ^ I believe this would be extremely resource heavy in my scenario as I am computing quite large datasets. Creating a new instance on each pass through could become quite taxing.

Comment: @Maff That's easily dealt with. I'm just pointing out that you don't need your own custom algorithm to see if a string contains a character from another string.

Comment: Has nothing to do with being in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

To call this method

```
-(BOOL) string:(NSString *)string1 containsCharInString:(NSString *)string2
```

you would say

```
[someObject string:someString containsCharInString:someOtherString]
```

Do you see?

I don't know the class of `someObject` because I don't know the class on which you have defined that method. But what I'm trying to show you is that every parameter counts. You can't just throw one away.

To put it another way: there is no selector `containsCharInString:` because that's not the name of the method you created. The method you created is called `string:containsCharInString:`. That may not be the method you wanted to create, but that is the method you did create.

Comment: `someObject` I believe would be irrelevant in my scenario as it is being invoked/used only within the one class `privately`. Thanks for the in depth answer though, much appreciated.

Comment: `someObject` would not be irrelevant. To call it on yourself, `someObject` would be `self`. You cannot omit the recipient of a message! It is very relevant always.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this rather than writing your own method.

```
NSString* aString = @"some string";

if ( [aString rangeOfString:@"different string"].location == NSNotFound )
```

Comment: Given the name of the OP's method, this is not what the code is trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps, looked to me like he was trying to see if a string contained a char, that line works great for such.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're trying to extend the behavior of the NSString class.

As others have pointed out, NSString already has very efficient methods like rangeOfCharacterFromSet to do this. Explore using one of those methods instead of writing custom code. If you're going to be doing it over and over, create an NSCharacterSet object and save it for reuse.

To your question, though, about making a call like this work:

```
if([string1 containsCharInString: word2]) {...}
```

One way to do this is to make string1 a custom object, possibly a subclass of NSString (not a good idea for beginners - NSString is what's called a "Class cluster", and those are tricky to subclass).

Probably the easiest way to do it would be to create a category of NSString. A category is a quirk of Objective-C that lets you add methods to existing classes without subclassing them. Categories can't add instance variables, just methods.

The interface for your category might look like this:

@interface NSString (containsChar)

- (BOOL) containsCharInString: (NSString *) string;
  @end

And then provide an implementation for the category method(s).